# Confused By Simple While Loop - Hiding Under Desk

Tags: java, string, while-loop

I am reading a book on Java and came across the following source code.

```
//This example demonstrates how to search multiple occurences of a search string
public class SearchString3 { 
    public static void main(String[] s) { 
        String str = "I am a student. I am preparing for OCPJP";
        int fromIndex = 0;
        while(str.indexOf("am", fromIndex) > -1) {
            fromIndex = str.indexOf("am", fromIndex);
            System.out.println("Substring \"am\" occrs at index: " + fromIndex);
            fromIndex++;

        } 
    }

}
```

I am confused how the "fromIndex" variable is incremented. It seems like the code in the while loop only runs twice but it must run for the entire length of the string. This code is from page 207 of Sharma and Ganesh's *Oracle Certified Professional Java SE 7 Programmer Exams 1Z0-804 and 1Z0-805*.

How is the fromIndex variable updated? It seems like the while loop would not be true except for two times. How is the while loop executing for every character of the string? Does anyone have any ideas how to add some code to debug this? Sorry my brain is not working today I did not get much sleep last night.

Comment: "How is the while loop executing for every character of the string?" -- It's not.

Comment: So how is the fromIndex variable incremented? Do you have any code to debug this?

Comment: You're already printing a line each time you loop, which includes the value of `fromIndex`.  How many print statements are you seeing? What is the value of `fromIndex` each time?

Comment: fromIndex = str.indexOf("am", fromIndex); will find the next index in the string that contains the string "am" starting at fromIndex, and therefore fromIndex won't be fromIndex + 1 each iteration, it will be the index where the next "am" occurs in `str`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At first round:

```
fromIndex = str.indexOf("am", fromIndex); // search from index 0, result is 2,  I (a)m a student, character (a)
System.out.println("Substring \"am\" occrs at index: " + fromIndex); // print ---> Substring "am" occrs at index: 2
fromIndex++; // increment fromIndex to 3
```

At second round:

```
fromIndex = str.indexOf("am", fromIndex); // search from index 3, I a(m) a student, character (m)
System.out.println("Substring \"am\" occrs at index: " + fromIndex); // print --->  Substring "am" occrs at index: 18
fromIndex++; // increment fromIndex to 19,  I a(m) prepa, the m character
```

finish.

Comment: Thank-you for the help. I forgot how the indexOf() method works. I forgot that this method searches from the index specified in the second argument.

Answer (score 1):

It's only executing twice if you change the loop to look like this its easy to see as the counter prints out `fromIndex = str.indexOf("am", fromIndex);` this sets the fromIndex variable the `fromIndex++;`
is incrementing to make sure they don't get stuck in an infinite loop of checking and to start checking the index after the point found

```
String str = "I am a student. I am preparing for OCPJP";
int fromIndex = 0;
int counter = 0;
while(str.indexOf("am", fromIndex) > -1) {
    System.out.println(++counter);
    fromIndex = str.indexOf("am", fromIndex);
    System.out.println("Substring \"am\" occrs at index: " + fromIndex);
    fromIndex++;
}
```

Output:

```
1
Substring "am" occrs at index: 2
2
Substring "am" occrs at index: 18
```

Comment: I like how you use the counter variable to only show the while loop runs twice.

Comment: I tried to make it easy to see the loop only runs twice

Answer (score 1):

`fromIndex` will only be updated with each match (and incremented once after each match). It won't pass through each element of the string.

However, `indexOf` will search through the string between each match, so the entire string will be evaluated, but most of that evaluation will happen inside `indexOf`.

Comment: Yes I forgot the 'indexOf' method searches the string. I was thinking trying to think...how is every character searched with this while loop and was baffled. Now I get it. The string is searched in the 'indexOf' method.

Answer (score 1):

Let's break it down.

During the ***first iteration,***

`fromIndex = 0;`

`fromIndex = str.indexOf("am", fromIndex); -------------------> gives 2`;

as indexOf() start from `fromIndex(here 0)` which updates `fromIndex = 2`

Next statement `fromIndex` is incremented by 1, so `fromIndex = 3`

***Second Iteration,***

`fromIndex = 3;`

`fromIndex = str.indexOf("am", fromIndex); -------------------> gives 18`;

as indexOf() start from `fromIndex(here 3)` which updates `fromIndex = 18`

Next statement `fromIndex` is incremented by 1, so `fromIndex = 19`

***Third Iteration,***

`fromIndex = 19`

`while` condition fails this time as there is no `am` after position `19`.

So the loop runs only twice and not the entire length of the string.

Comment: Under your "Second iteration" heading I think fromIndex = 3 is correct but you have fromIndex = 2.

Comment: I like the breakdown

Comment: @user3870315 fixed it.. Matt Thanks. Happy to help.